# $\lim_{n\to\infty} ((\sum_{k=1}^{n} f(\frac{k}{n^2})) -nf(0))$

Tags: calculus, summation

Edit:$f$ is defined on [-1,1] and $f'(0)$ exists

The only thing that came to mind was pairing it n pairs of $f(\frac{k}{n^2}) -f(0)$ but that doesn't seem to work--Its not a Reimann sum either....can anyone give me any ideas? The final answer is $\frac{1}{2}f'(0)$, but I can't seem to work it out-- thanks!

Comment: So the question probably requires that $f$ should be taken as differentiable (at least at $0$), right?

Comment: @MarkViola Seems to me just assuming differentiable at $0$ is enough.

Comment: @davidc.ullrich Hi David.  I hope you're well and staying safe and healthy.   It is sufficient.  I was trying to prompt the OP to state conditions.

Comment: @MarkViola  edited, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Note $$f\left(\frac k{n^2}\right)-f(0)=\frac k{n^2}\frac{f\left(\frac k{n^2}\right)-f(0)}{\frac k{n^2}-0}=\frac k{n^2}\frac{f(h_k(n))-f(0)}{h_k(n)-0},$$if $h_k(n)=k/n^2$. And note that if $\delta>0$ there exists $N$ such that if $n>N$ then $0<h_k(n)<\delta$ for $k=1,2,\dots n$.

Let $\epsilon>0$. Choose $\delta>0$ so $|h|<\delta$ implies $|(f(h)-f(0))/h - f'(0)|<\epsilon$, choose $N$ as above and suppose $n>N$. Then $$\begin{align}\left|\left(\left(\sum_{k=1}^nf\left(\frac k{n^2}\right)-nf(0)\right)-\frac{n(n+1)}{2n^2} f'(0)\right)\right|
&=\left|\sum_{k=1}^n\left[\left(f\left(\frac k{n^2}\right)-f(0)\right)-\frac k{n^2}f'(0)\right]\right|
\\&\le\sum_{k=1}^n\left|\left(f\left(\frac k{n^2}\right)-f(0)\right)-\frac k{n^2}f'(0)\right|
\\&\le \sum_{k=1}^n\frac k{n^2}\left|\frac{f\left(\frac k{n^2}\right)-f(0)}{\frac k{n^2}-0}-f'(0)\right|
\\&\le\epsilon\sum_{k=1}^n\frac k{n^2}
\\&<\epsilon.\end{align}$$

So the expression on the left of that display tends to $0$. Since $\frac{n(n+1)}{2n^2}f'(0)-\frac12f'(0)$ also tends to $0$ we're done.

Comment: Could you elaborate more on your hint? I don't know where to go next- Thanks!

Comment: Well, that $(f(h)-f(0))/h$ is close to $f'(0)$. And $\sum k/n^2$ is close to $1/2$...

Comment: "So the expression on the left of that display tends to 0" I'm sorry, what, exactly? And how does  "n(n−1)/2n^2 f′(0)−f(0) also tends to 0" imply that the limit is equal to 1/2 f'(0)?

Comment: Say $\left|\left(\left(\sum_{k=1}^nf\left(\frac k{n^2}\right)-nf(0)\right)-\frac{n(n-1)}{2n^2} f'(0)\right)\right|=a_n$. We've shown that for every $\epsilon>0$ there exists $N$ so $|a_n|<\epsilon$ for all $n>N$. This says exactly $a_n\to0$ by definition. Regarding your second question, there was a typo; the corrected version of the last sentence may make more sense. (Finally, $a_n\to0$ and $b_n\to0$ imply $a_n+b_n\to0$.)

Comment: @LeeLaindingold Speaking of typos, in two places $n(n-1)$ should have been $n(n+1)$.